# Set Android preference file that my Preference objects save to?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

In my application I am trying to add support for different profiles. Each of these profiles can have their own independent Preferences, configured from a deep tree of custom and stock preference objects.

I thought that I could add this easily by using different Preference Files per profile, as in `getSharedPreferences("george", MODE_PRIVATE);` would store them for profile "george".
The issue I am having is the Preference objects seem to be storing their values in the default  Preference file. Is there any way from my Activity or Fragment to change which Preference file is used by the Preferences on my Preference Screen? I know this doesn't exist, but I'm looking for something like `.setPreferenceFile(String filename)` for a Preference or PreferenceGroup.

Any help or suggestions to minimize the work to support independent profile preferences will be appreciated..